# Centering text over matrix columns

Tags: matrices

How can I modify the code below to get the text centered over the matrix columns with `1`s instead of aligned to the left edge of the columns.

Below is the MWE code and output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% command for overbrace in matrix
\newcommand\bovermat[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\overbrace{\phantom{%
    \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}^{#1}}$}#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
   0 & \cdots & 0
   & \bovermat{\text{columns }q_1,\ldots,q_\ell}{1 & \cdots & 1} 
   & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
   0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
   \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & & & \vdots \\
   0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Try to remove the `&` that precedes the `\bovermat` and put it *inside* the `\bovermat`. Like this: `\bovermat{\text{columns }q_1,\ldots,q_\ell}{& 1 & \cdots & 1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `blkarray`, it has more flexibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccccccc}
& & & & \makebox[0pt]{$\overbrace{\rule{4em}{0pt}}^{\text{columns }q_1,\ldots,q_\ell}$} & & & & \\
\begin{block}{[ccccccccc]}
   0    & \cdots &   0    &   1    & \cdots &   1    & 0 & \cdots &   0    \\
   0    & \cdots &   0    &   1    & \cdots &   1    & 0 & \cdots &   0    \\
 \vdots &        & \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &   &        & \vdots \\
   0    & \cdots &   0    &   1    & \cdots &   1    & 0 & \cdots &   0    \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments section by Phelype Oleinik, the solution is to remove the `&` that precedes the `\bovermat` and to put it inside the second argument to `\bovermat`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% command for overbrace in matrix
\newcommand\bovermat[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\overbrace{\phantom{%
    \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}^{#1}}$}#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}   \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
   0 & \cdots & 0
   \bovermat{ \text{columns }q_1,\ldots,q_\ell}{& 1 & \cdots & 1} 
   & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
   0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
   \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & & & \vdots \\
   0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right]

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE corrected]